# ssh-keygen and ssh-add passphrase problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

When I run `ssh-keygen` and press return instead of inputting a password then I can add the key with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I am prompted to enter the passphre for `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I simply press enter and all is well.

However - when I do input a password at `ssh-keygen` stage, and then reenter the same password at `ssh-add` stage it fails with `bad passphrase, try again`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried this with cutting & pasting the password, thus making sure it is definitely not mistyped?

Comment: I used passwords such as "password", and "pass", which is hard to mistype - but I will try pasting.

Comment: I'm sure you did, this is just to exclude the possibility.

Comment: That looks like an encoding problem, maybe ? what does `env | grep LANG`gives you ?

Comment: @Kwaio out:

"LANG=en_GB.UTF-8" and
"LANGUAGE=en_GB:en"

What should we expect?

Comment: I copied and pasted the password and no luck - the same problem happened.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the **private** key to the ssh-agent, not the public key. The default key name is id_rsa, so you don't even need any options:

```
ssh-add
```

If you've named your key something else (e.g.) `github_dsa`, then use:

```
ssh-add github_dsa
```

Note to internet interlopers: if you didn't use ssh-keygen to generate the key, make sure your key is in SSH format. For PuttyGen, for example, there's an export option that you need to use.